# Consider certain string as variable

Tags: php

my php script gets a json config file. In this case, $json->autowelcome is "Hello {user}, welcome!"

I want php to interpreter the {user} as $user. How can i do that?

```
        // Answer to tickle every 5 seconds
        if (time() - dataAPI::get($key) >= 5) {
            dataAPI::set($key, time());
            $bot->network->answerTickle($who);
            $name = $bot->users[$who]->getRegname();
                $bot->network->sendMessageAutoDetection($who, $bot->botData['ontickle'], 2,true);

        }
```

Comment: the *evil* eval() comes to mind

Comment: post code that is relevant to the text of the question please.

Comment: not being able to see the code behind `$json->autowelcome` if autowelcome is a function you could use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in it like `str_replace("{user}",$user,""Hello {user}, welcome!")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you to use str_replace. Easier way.

Exemple:

```
$string   = 'Hello {name}!';
$search[] = '{id}';            $replace[] = $user->getID();
$search[] = '{name}';          $replace[] = $user->getNick();
$search[] = '{regname}';       $replace[] = $user->getRegname();
return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: assumes you know all the possible variables to start with

Comment: @nogad hehe, he's the developer of the project i am testing for. He knows all the variables.